# How to check a string is html encoded or not?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-web-api, encode

I am working with my web API. Some user send parameter string as HTML encoded I want to identify the coming parameters are HTML encoded or plain text.

My Web API method is

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string Accesskey, string AccessPwd)
{
   // code logic
}
```

i am getting Accesskey as Html Encoded like

```
Accesskey="AbIfZVn4y514sJbt%2BCCMJy6lsmsMi6uOWyhUhynDSf1MEqZ%2FWJnwUuCFO8zMFa4jCRWQrXHKdBaHd9CCdDNfoKDnPg1W9No16JQbL2DBEGg%3D";
```

i want output like

```
Accesskey="AbIfZVn4y514sJbt+CCMJy6lsmsMi6uOWyhUhynDSf1MEqZ/WJnwUuCFO8zMFa4jCRWQrXHKdBaHd9CCdDNfoKDnPg1W9No16JQbL2DBEGg="
```

Comment: Is `%20` plain text of HTML encoded value?

Comment: You can try playing with the Uri() class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes @Levenko. I am getting this type of string.

Comment: No need to check. Simply html decode incoming string and use. If the string is htm encoded then you would get decoded string and if it isn't then you would get the actual plain string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A technique should be to force URL decoding and check if result is the same as source string.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

var incomingStrings = new[] { "not encoded", "encod&eacute;d" };

foreach (var incomingString in incomingStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsUrlEncoded(incomingString));
}

private bool IsUrlEncoded(string source)
{
    return source != HttpUtility.UrlDecode(source);
}
```

Comment: When you click on "Run code from Gistlyn", is it working?

Comment: Your code is working.but if i have HTML encoded string then its not working. i have updated my question see encoded string above AccessKey

Comment: You are mixing HTML encoding and URL encoding. See my edits

Comment: You welcome. Please mark it as the solution if it is. Thanks.

Comment: @labilbe This is not valid for `CJK` strings.

Comment: @Mayank UrlDecode uses UTF8 as default encoding. So CJK strings should work.

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem as well. My text value is not always encoded HTML, it can be just encoded text.
When I use a method like

> HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value)

it always return the same text, not decoded. So it is not work for me.

To resolve it, I used a rough way by checking if the string is typically an encoded text.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length % 4 == 0 && !value.Contains(" ") && 
!value.Contains("\t") && !value.Contains("\r") && !value.Contains("\n"))
{
    // it's encoded text value
}
```

- Encoded text's length is always multiple of 4.
- Encoded text always never has any space.
- Encoded text always never has any tab or newline character.

Comment: The OP's text doesn't appear to be a multiple of 4. Can you provide sample strings?

Comment: @Enigmativity As stated in my answer, it's the Encoded Text that will always have length multiple of 4. Not Encoded URL or HTML. This answer just provides an idea on how to check whether if the text is encoded or not.

Answer (score -4):

You can just use

```
console.log('yourtext');
```

It will show as original in console.